# Delete temporary files

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, jersey, multipartform-data

I have developed a rest client using spring mvc which upload files and form data to a rest service using Jersey.

I can able to see the files that i uploaded, in rest client's Tomcat home directory.

How can i automatically delete the file that is stored in my tomcat, after i get a success response.

Some of my configuration for your reference,

Multipart config in "web.xml"

```
  <multipart-config>
      <location>/tmp</location>
      <max-file-size>26214400</max-file-size>
      <max-request-size>31457280</max-request-size>
      <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
  </multipart-config>
```

multipart config in "dispatcher-servlet.xml"

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver"/>
```

My business logic,

```
public Map<Object, Object> upload(ModelMap model) {
        Map<Object, Object> responseMap = new HashMap<>();
        sendMailBean = (SendMailBean) model.get("sendMailBean");

        FormDataMultiPart formDataMultiPart = new FormDataMultiPart();
        formDataMultiPart.field("firstName", sendMailBean.getFirstname());
        formDataMultiPart.field("lastName", sendMailBean.getLastname());
        formDataMultiPart.field("fromAddress", sendMailBean.getEmail());
        formDataMultiPart.field("subject", sendMailBean.getSubject());
        formDataMultiPart.field("text", sendMailBean.getMessage());
        List<MultipartFile> files = sendMailBean.getAttachments();
        try {
            for(MultipartFile file : files) {
                File convFile = convert(file);
                FileDataBodyPart filePart = new FileDataBodyPart("files", convFile);
                filePart.setContentDisposition(FormDataContentDisposition.name("files").fileName(file.getOriginalFilename()).build());
                formDataMultiPart.bodyPart(filePart);
            }
            Client client = new Client();       
            WebResource webResource = client.resource(----rest url-----);
            ClientResponse response = webResource.type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA).post(ClientResponse.class, formDataMultiPart);


            if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
                model.addAttribute("errormsg", "Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatus());
                responseMap.put("model", model);
                responseMap.put("redirectToPage", "redirect:/views/error");
            } else {
                //          responseMap.put("redirectToPage", "/views/email");

                responseMap.put("model", model);
                responseMap.put("redirectToPage", "");
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return responseMap;
    }

    public File convert(MultipartFile file)
    {    
        File convFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
        try {
            convFile.createNewFile(); 
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(convFile); 
            fos.write(file.getBytes());
            fos.close(); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return convFile;
    }
```

Comment: it's unrelated to your original question, but you should _never_ trust the incoming file name, at least in terms of writing to the local filesystem.  in your current code, a malicious client could force you to overwrite sensitive files with the uploaded file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem lies with the fileoutstream logic to convert multipart file to file. Below is the workaround that i used to resolve this,

I replaced the conversion logic to,

```
public File multipartToFile(MultipartFile file) throws IllegalStateException, IOException 
    {

        File tmpFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + file.getOriginalFilename());
        file.transferTo(tmpFile);
        return tmpFile;
    }
```

and for each multipart file iteration, i have put the converted file to a list and after I finished uploading the file, I iterated my list and deleted the file.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem.
The best way for GC to delete the tmp file is to ensure your inputstream is closed after using it.

```
} finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException io) {

                }
            }
}
```

For some odd reason the `inputstream` stays open even after your rest service executes; this prevents the GC collect and delete it.